# HighCharts always throw error #16

Tags: highcharts

I have this code, where the example runs perfect, but If I open Chrome console it always raises highchart error #16, do anybody knows why?

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            "exporting":{"enabled":true},
            "title":{"text":"Fruit Consumption"},

            "xAxis":{"categories":["Apples","Bananas","Oranges"]},
            "yAxis":{"title":{"text":"Fruit eaten"}},
            "series":[{"name":"Jane","data":[1,0,4]},{"name":"John","data":[5,7,3]}],
            chart:{renderTo:'container'}
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm using chrome and I don't see that error http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/6UuS3/. Do you have other code that might be interfering?

Comment: Error is exactly as in description: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16 - make sure that you have included highcharts.js only once.

Comment: @PawełFus highcharts is only once because Im testing how it works, so I prepare a view with that code. Could it be another problem, like jquery js, or another js that makes that problem in my app?

Comment: This is part of Highcharts code: `windows.Highcharts = windows.Highcharts ? error(16, true) : {};` They just checks if Highcharts variable is already defined and it is. Maybe you are including Highcharts and Highstock? Use only one of them (Highstock contains Highcharts).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're loading Highcharts.js in the HTML body.  If you look at the installation docs, it says to load the script in the `<head></head>` tags.  I was having the same problem as you so I threw in a break point at the line referenced in the comments above:

```
windows.Highcharts = windows.Highcharts ? error(16, true) : {};
```

What I found was that the breakpoint would break twice.  the first time it fired, during the browser parsing the Highcharts.js would establish the Highcharts namespace.  Next time around, it would fire error #16.  this would only occur when I loaded the script at the end of the Html page which was part of an effort to improve the performance of the JavaScript loading on our site. Putting it back in the head eliminated the problem. I'm not sure if there's a workaround yet.  Still looking into it.